# Is Msmq reliable?

Tags: msmq, message-queuing, jms

Maybe a subjective question, but is Msmq reliable compared to JMS solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no reliability issues with MSMQ unless you are have to many different machines connecting to one MSMQ service.  We maxed out at 2-3 servers sending to a queue instance and 2-3 servers reading from a queue instance.  Keep in mind that we send millions of messages per minute through the queues.

Comment: Millions of message/minutes = yes, MSMQ is reliable.

Answer (score 2):

Udi Dahan, of NServiceBus, has written about using NServiceBus backed by MSMQ on his blog [here](http://www.udidahan.com/2008/05/21/nservicebus-performance/). The discussion is more about performance than reliability, but you should find it an interesting read.

[Here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/1791) is someone running 500 messages a second through NServiceBus (again backed by MSMQ) without any issues.

I've only used MSMQ for applications with much lighter loads, but I've never experienced any reliability issues.

Comment: Not knocking it, but with RabbitMQ, we regularly send 10,000/s with minimal load.

Comment: @Basic it was just an example from yesteryear :)  FWIW, in real world projects these days I see around the same, or much higher if messages are batched (e.g. 1M+/s).

Answer (score 0):

In addition: it is as realiable as you make it. Depending on configuration you may loose all messges on a server restart. This is a configuration choice, though (faster, queue only in memory).